how to disable the enforceFocus property applied by bootstrap modal
I have a Chrome extension that injects and opens a modal on other websites, the modal of my chrome extension is made using pure HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. When my extension opens modal on a website that has another bootstrap modal already open then due to enforceFocus property of the bootstrap modal being true, the textarea on my extension modal looses focus. I know the fact that on passing enforceFocus={false} in bootstrap modal component as --
<Modal enforceFocus={false}>
....
</Modal>

this problem gets solved but ofcourse i can't alter modal code of other websites. I want that when my extension modal opens then enforceFocus of bootstrap modal should become false only as long as my extension modal is open . Is there a way to make enforceFocus of bootstrap modal as false by writing javascript code in my chrome extension ?
in my case my modal is made purely out of HTML and CSS no bootstrap used and when i open my modal over another bootstrap modal then bootstrap modal steals focus from my modal because of it's inbuilt behaviour. I am just injecting my modal in the body on websites and then later removing it from body once work is done using webpack and javascript. Below is the relevant code --
import "../modal/modal.scss";
import modalHtml from "./modal.html";
 const parser = new DOMParser();
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(modalHtml, "text/html");
  const bodyHTML = doc.body.innerHTML;
  const modalContainer = document.createElement("div");
  modalContainer.innerHTML = bodyHTML;
  document.body.appendChild(modalContainer);

As you can see the webpack provides me with HTML code of modal.html which i further parse and inject using js. The CSS gets injected by webpack when i import CSS as done above. When i tried using shadow DOM as --
modalContainer.attachShadow({mode:'open'}).innerHTML = htmlContent

my modal got injected without any CSS so it wasn't looking like a modal at all . And as i said my modal is made of pure HTML,CSS so there is no variable i am using to open or close or handle it's state just injecting and removing. So how to use this shadowDOM property to avoid bootstrap modals from stealing focus from my modal if i open my modal over an already open bootstrap modal.

Try adding your UI inside a shadow DOM.

@wOxxOm can you please explain what do you mean by this ??Currently i am injecting my modal using content script like this ---
const modalDataURL = chrome.runtime.getURL("modal.html");   fetch(modalDataURL)     .then((response) => response.text())     .then((htmlContent) => {       const parser = new DOMParser();       const doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlContent, "text/html");       const bodyHTML = doc.body.innerHTML;       const modalContainer = document.createElement("div");       modalContainer.innerHTML = bodyHTML;       document.body.appendChild(modalContainer);

are you asking to create a shadow kind od DOM in body and then add my modal inside it it do you mean something else?

modalContainer.attachShadow({mode:'open'}).innerHTML = htmlContent and remove DOMParser.

@wOxxOm i have changed my code a little bit because now i am using webpack and now it's const parser = new DOMParser();   const doc = parser.parseFromString(modalHtml, "text/html");   const bodyHTML = doc.body.innerHTML;   const modalContainer = document.createElement("div");   modalContainer.innerHTML = bodyHTML;   document.body.appendChild(modalContainer);
your suggested method doesn't work for me modal is not opening i just see all contents of modal.html getting injected without any modal

can you please tell how to handle this, my modalHtml is the HTML which webpack compiles and  gives me

Add all the relevant code to the question, see MCVE.

@woxxom can you please have a look at my question again now I have added relevant codes and details
